# Android: Textview not showing the value set programatically

Tags: java, android

I want to set the value of textview programatically, everything seems okay by me but dont know why the set value is not appearing

This is the code:

```
//set the value of a text view
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.validityValue);
            textView.setText("30 days");
```

This is what I have in my xml file

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/validityValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
```

With the above code, the textview is not showing when the application launched.

UPDATE////////
Complete xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
     android:background="@drawable/mobilegrd"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Weekly Updates" />
  <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinTunes"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="6sp"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:prompt="@string/tune_prompt" />

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Singer:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/singer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"/>

    <!-- android:inputType="phone"  -->
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Language:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/language"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Price:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/validityValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/validity"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/proceed"
    android:text="Proceed"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It's looks valid, there is probably some thing else that you are missing. Please provide us more of your code.

Comment: The log throws exception?

Comment: your text color android:textColor="#000" may be the probelm, try with some other color

Comment: Please post your xml

Comment: put complete code of xml layout. check textview be in right place in device and also textcolor of textview be different of your back ground. you can remove  `android:textColor="#000"` and test it.

Comment: What you have tried ? provided the details you did instated of not working/same result

Comment: you have to add text line in xml whether you set it to "" but I think you have to
like 
android:text=""

Comment: Can you post full xml layout? Everything seems fine with your code

Comment: Please check my update

Comment: What about the other text views, is they are working ?

Comment: Yeah there are working!

Comment: android:textSize="12sp" is the one which is not in others, so remove this and try too

Comment: Hi, my answer solve your problem?

Comment: No. Tried it but it didnt work. Is included in the update

Comment: Actually will you let us know where is those codes in java class. Is it inside oncreate method ?? or in some anonymous method ? If this is in onCreate method then why are you declaring it as final ?

Comment: Check the answer logs of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be something in front of it, try:

```
textView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 3):

Review properly that `id` is not conflicted..Please be sure that you don't have same id of `TextView` in two fragments for tab in `viewpager` If you are using those...

Comment: There is no id conflict

Answer (score 2):

At first Change Your `android:textColor` .Use This

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```

Then

```
  final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.validityValue);
    textView.setText("30 days");
    String str1 = textView.getText().toString();
    Log.d("++++++",str1);
```

Then check What **Log.d** returns .

If `Log.d` returns properly then post your **Total XML** .

Comment: This is identical to '#000'

Comment: This is what we said in comments

Comment: @JnG is there any problem if you remove `final` ?

Comment: @JnG Strange case .Okay .Remove `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` for testing case . Increase Text size

Comment: Upvoting your answer for your nice suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code in your xml and run your application. Let me know what happens.

```
    android:text="New Text"
```

Comment: Is other textviews are visible? will you add screenshot of  that page after runnning?

Answer (score 0):

Check your activity. Its likely you are calling setContentView again after textView.setText("30 days");